# How do I create a new Slideshow in the header?

Tags: 7, views

I've inherited a site with a functioning Slideshow. I haven't been able to figure out how that appears on the site. And I'd like something similar to the functioning Slideshow in the header and have been unable to get that to work. The functioning Slideshow is comprised of:

A Panel Node with content:

- View: Slideshow: Slideshow Block
- Welcome Message Block
- View:Featured Articles: Featured News Block
- Home page mini

None of the objects, that I have been able to find, are set to appear (any place I can find), yet the home page shows all the appropriate stuff.

I've tried creating a new Panel Node with all the same content and it doesn't appear. I've tried creating a New Slideshow Block and putting it in the Header Region and the first image appears without rotation.

I'm confused and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess since the information provided is very limited: Often slideshows in the header are output as background images on the theme level. So maybe you should have a look at your page.tpl.php (and maybe also your template.php) to see if at some point the view is called from there and not from the panel.

Comment: I've found lots of of those. Perhaps you can help me figure out which one(s) apply.

#find . -name page.tpl.php
./sites/all/themes/successinc/page.tpl.php
./sites/all/themes/saprivateschools/templates/page.tpl.php
./sites/all/themes/zen/templates/page.tpl.php
./new/themes/garland/page.tpl.php
./new/themes/seven/page.tpl.php
./new/themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php
./new/modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme/page.tpl.php
./new/modules/system/page.tpl.php
./themes/garland/page.tpl.php
./themes/seven/page.tpl.php
./themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php

Comment: Please go to /admin/build/themes/select and check which theme is in use. It should be the one that is set as standard. Once you get the name of the active theme, check in the folder with that name. For example, if "Bartik" is the theme in use, have a look at bartik/templates/page.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same thing to do this week.  Do you have a HTML.inc and a slide.inc file.   If it's the same set up it's pretty straight forward.  it loads the variable $slide with $panel info that you call back sequentially.

Could you post some code up and I'll see if it's the same and whether I can help you.

Comment: I can't find any HTML.inc or slide.inc. And there's no special code that I see, everything is done with standard modules.

Comment: I think you need to start by using one of the devel modules, these can help you understand what module and themes and classes are being used to create things https://drupal.org/node/1779516. That and using search in your IDE .